# Dynamically adding key, value parsed array put into Object.property = value schema

Tags: c#, object

I have an object defined as follows:

```
public class Variable
{
    public string varName { get; set; }
    public double varVal { get; set; }
    public double varParam { get; set; }

    public Variable(string varName1, double varVal1 = 1, double varParam1 = 0)
    {
        varName = varName1;
        varVal = varVal1;
        varParam = varParam1;
    }
}
```

I have this object in a list that needs to be accessed by many methods in the parent class as follows:

```
public static List<Variable> variableList = new List<Variable>();
```

I have an input on a text file that I'm using `.Split(",")` to put into a string array in any order and possibly missing key-values (besides name):

```
varName,Test,varVal,1.0101,varParam,3.03
```

so in my code, after I use `.Split(",")` for this text line:

```
string readKeyvalue[] = { "varName","Test","varVal","1.0101","varParam","3.03" }
```

I must stress that only `varName` key-pair will be required in the text file, and all of these can be in any order. I want to put them into object properties in the structure like follows (pseudocode):

```
variableList[0].varName == Test
variableList[0].varVal == 1.0101
variableList[0].varParam == 3.03
```

I have failed in my previous efforts to make this possible through sorting the array (which works) and using the following as can be reference in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759917/c-sharp-how-to-use-variables-as-property-names-in-an-object-list-object-construc). This line is for the case of a missing `varVal`, but sorted into a string array of `varName,Test,varParam,3.03`:

```
materialList.Add(new Material(sortedVals[1]) { $sortedVals[2] = Convert.ToDouble(sortedVals[3]) } ) ;
```

As you can see, this does not work because `sortedVals[2]` is not recognized by the compiler as a member declarator, and I can find no way (without 2-3 more classes just for converting the string into a property then brute forcing my way through tons of code) to assign all of the available values to properties while skipping the missing ones.

So to clarify, I can't find a way to assign the available properties to an object while disregarding any missing objects without hardcoding in each and every case (which will be very difficult when I have an object with 10-12 properties).

If anyone has any wisdom, I would be very grateful!

Comment: So your actual question is: how do I parse `varName,Test,varVal,1.0101,varParam,3.03` when the order of `varName`, `varVal` and `varParam` can be random (but they are always followed by their related values)? Is that correct?

Comment: Why don't use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` for that?

Comment: @MattBurland Nope, I can reorder them just fine. The problem is that if one is missing, then objects seem to not inherently have a handler for that since members can't be identified by a variable. I can't find a way to correctly add the present key-values and skip the missing key-values without hardcoding each possible case

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I decided to use an object list instead of a dictionary because then the object is clearly defined, so sorting will be on the object. If I use dictionaries instead, won't it just be a large conglomeration of key-value pairs without that identifier of object and its properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm understanding your question, one approach is to parse your input string into a dictionary. Something like this:

```
var input = "varName,Test,varVal,1.0101,varParam,3.03";

var grouped = input.Split(',').Select((str,idx) => new {str, idx})
    .GroupBy(g => g.idx / 2)
    .Select(g => g.Select(s => s.str).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(grouped.First().ToString());
var dictionary = grouped.ToDictionary(g => g[0], k => k[1]);
```

The idea is to split your string and then group it into pairs of values (grouping by the index / 2 which will truncate because it's integer division). From there you can convert the pairs into arrays (of two values) and then to a dictionary keyed off the first value of each pair.

Then you can populate your object by using the database keys, testing for their presence:

```
variableList[0].varName = dictionary.TryGetValue("varName", out var s) ? s : null;
variableList[0].varVal = dictionary.TryGetValue("varVal", out var s) ? double.TryParse(s, out var d) ? d : 0.0 : 0.0;
variableList[0].varParam = dictionary.TryGetValue("varParam", out var s) ? double.TryParse(s, out var d) ? d : 0.0;
```

I used `double.TryParse` and falling back to 0 if the string is malformed, but you might want to actually handle that differently.

Comment: [A dotnetfiddle.net for the code above, because I was having trouble following it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iKo8H9). :)

Comment: To clarify, would the dictionary tryGetValue simply not return a value if it doesn't exist on line 3? That might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks to @HereticMonkey, I also tried to input my class, variable List, and your code combined using the .Add function to create the new List item instance. It comes with a host of errors: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CYU6VQ

Comment: That was my bad; Matt used some newer C# functionality and I used the wrong compiler. Try https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ilc4VM.